# Rebind RadTreeView from another user control

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a GrandParent User Control top.asxc. Inside i have a radSplitter control which divides the page into 2 sections. On the Left Section i load inside the Left.ascx control which inside has a radTreeView and on the right side the right.ascx. On the right.ascx control i have a button and when i Click it i wantn to Databind the radTreeView control which is on the left.ascx control. Is that a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event from the right.ascx `UserControl` to the top.ascx `UserControl`. Then the top.ascx `UserControl` will trigger the event you want, since top.ascx does have an instance of left.ascx. Here is how...

**In the right.ascx.cs file**:

```
public event EventHandler RightButton_Clicked;

protected void RightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = RightButton_Clicked;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

**In the top.ascx.cs file**:

```
private static Control _leftUC;
private static Control _rightUC;

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnInit(e);
     InitWebUserControls();
}

// Note: if your UserControl is defined in the ascx Page, use that definition
//       instead of the dynamically loaded control `_right_UC`. Same for `_leftUC`
private void InitWebUserControls()
{
     _leftUC = Page.LoadControl("left.ascx");
     _rightUC = Page.LoadControl("right.ascx");
     ((right)_rightUC).RightButton_Clicked += new EventHandler(RightUC_Event);
}

void RightUC_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((left)_leftUC ).UpdateControl();
}
```

**In the left.ascx file**:

```
public void UpdateControl()
{
     leftRadTreeView.Rebind();
}
```

---

If you eventually want to pass an event argument to the top.ascx `UserControl`, instead of using `new EventArgs()` use a custom class which implements `EventArgs` and use it this way:

```
int myArgument = 1;
handler(this, new RightEventArgs(myArgument));

public class RightEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public int argumentId;

    public RightEventArgs(int selectedValue)
    {
        argumentId = selectedValue;
    }
}
```

And then you can filter the events that were passed to top.ascx by verifying its `EventArgs` concrete type:

```
private void InitWebUserControls()
{
     _leftUC = Page.LoadControl("left.ascx");
     ((left)_leftUC ).LeftButton_Clicked += new EventHandler(Child_Event);
     _rightUC = Page.LoadControl("right.ascx");
     ((right)_rightUC).RightButton_Clicked += new EventHandler(Child_Event);
}

void Child_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if( e is RightEventArgs)
     {
          ((left)_leftUC).UpdateControl();
     }
     else if (e is LeftEventArgs)
     {
          ((right)_rightUC).ClearSelection();
     }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, and when i debug it does not pass the condition  if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }

Comment: You mean this portion of code is not called? The `RightButton_Click` method should be the one called once you click The button...so make sure you specified in your aspx file `OnClick="RightButton_Click"`.

Comment: Make sure the `InitWebUserControls()` method is called before entering the `RightButton_Click` event. Have you set that button to `AutoPostBack="true"` ?